# Is there any way to get pending transaction for specified address using Web3Py?

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

is there any way to get pending transaction for a specified address? I can filter them on bscscan [here](https://bscscan.com/txsPending?a=0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56&m=hf), but I can't do the same in my web3py code. I can get all pending transaction for current pending block but I can't filter them. I can do:

```
txHashPending = w3.eth.filter('latest').get_all_entries()
```

and I get transactionHashes for pending transactions. I tried doing:

```
txHashPending = w3.eth.filter({'fromBlock':'pending','toBlock':'pending','from':'0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56'}).get_all_entries()
```

but it returned already validated/mined transactions.